# Incorporating Exploratory Tests created using the Test & Feedback extension in to existing Test Suites

Tags: testing, azure-devops

We are embarking on the delivery of a large D365 ERP. As Test Manager I'll be creating  some tests with normal Pass/Fail criteria which can be easily reported on. The bulk of the testing will be done by our project SMEs & other business users.  For some of the larger modules we could have up to 20 people executing test scenarios. Rather than them having to test using Excel I'd like them to use the Test & Feedback extension and create Exploratory Tests when they test a feature/business scenario.

When they are using the extension they will be linking back to the parent item in the Test Suite (either a PBI or a Test Case).  These Exploratory Tests then display as 'Related' to the item in the Test Suite.  So that the project can fully understand the required test effort I'd like to get Exploratory Tests added to the Test Suites, and subsequently reported on the Dashboard.

I've gotten stuck with the last part and am wondering if anyone on here can help with some answers/advice for the following:

1. Is there a way for a Test Suite to update dynamically (or otherwise) when Exploratory Tests are linked to items in the Test Suite? There doesn't appear to be a way to rerun a query to add items to an existing Test Suite (I can go and recreate the Test Suite using a Query and get the items in, but I lose the test results for other items in the suite)
2. Is anyone aware of a widget that will allow me to report on Exploratory Tests?

Comment: Regarding the second question,AFAIK,there is currently no such widget.Widgets are implemented as a [contribution point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/?view=azure-devops) in the extension framework. You can try to build a custom widget extension to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for a Test Suite to update dynamically (or otherwise)
>   when Exploratory Tests are linked to items in the Test Suite?

For this issue, when you create a test suite ,there are three types to choose from : static test suites, requirement-based suites, and query-based suites. I think [query-based suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-what-are-query-based-test-suites-) could meet your need.

[image]

What are query-based test suites :
Use a query to group together test cases that have a particular characteristic, for example, all tests that have Priority=1. The suite will automatically include every test case that is returned by the query that you define.

> Is anyone aware of a widget that will allow me to report on
>   Exploratory Tests?

Regarding the second question,AFAIK,there is currently no such widget.Widgets are implemented as a [contribution point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/?view=azure-devops) in the extension framework. You can try to build a custom widget extension to achieve this feature.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I started using the query based suites and using a keyword as an identifier (using 'Title contains' in my query). I've further noticed that if add the Creation Date parameter then I'll be returned with a daily view of Exploratory Testing.  Also, query based suites do dynamically update, so there's no loss of test history.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.Have a nice day:)